# Can Alexa determine a switch state?

Tags: alexa

I have a virtual switch set up through Hubitat that actually opens and closes my garage door. I can say "Alexa open Pete" and she will turn the virtual switch on which opens the garage door. Also I can say "Alexa close Pete" to close the garage. The problem I am having is if I ask her "Alexa is Pete open?" I want her to determine the status of the switch. I am even ok if she responds "Pete is on" instead of "Pete is open" but I can't get that far even.

I have tried (based on searches of things to try)

- Assigning the switch to a room called garage and saying "Alexa is Garage Pete on / open?"
- Saying "Alexa what is status on Hubitat of Pete?"

The problem seems like it should be pretty simple as it is really determining if a light / switch is on or off but I can't figure how for her to report the status / state of a device at all. Is that something she doesn't support?

FYI if you didn't figure out, Pete is the name of my virtual switch for the garage door :)

Comment: I would think you would first need to look at Hubitat.  What are the possible commands that Hubitat has created to work with Alexa?

Comment: This really doesn't have to do with Hubitat so much. If I have a switch connected to Alexa directly, how would I view its state normally? (with no Hubitat involved) @dmikester1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexa has updated their software to directly support garage openers. Now I can hook up the garage opener through Hubitat as a garage opener (no more having to trick things using virtual devices) and Alexa sees the garage opener as a garage opener (no more tricking).

This allows her to directly open and close the garage opener and report back its state.  I can now say "Alexa is garage opener open?" And she will reply correctly.